# Playing WAV or MP3 file in pyqt5 (Python 3.9)

Tags: python, pyqt5, mp3, wav

I need an MP3 or WAV file played when I push a button on GUI dialog box I created. I've tried using some modules like Pyaudio and Winsound but nothing worked for me.

Maybe there is a way like defining a function which will contain path to a sound file and then call it by pushing a button?

Here's the code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QToolTip, QLabel, QDialog
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys


class Window2(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Audiometry Test")
        self.setGeometry(750, 250, 350, 200)
        self.main_text = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)


        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.btn.move(140, 100)
        self.btn.setText("125 HZ signal")
        self.btn.adjustSize()
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take your time to follow the [tour] and read [ask] good questions; also consider that things like "I've tried [xyz] but nothing worked for me" are not very useful to your questions (why didn't it work? what was the problem?), as much as showing code that does not actually attempt to do what you're trying to achieve (the code you provided just creates a UI). Instead, try to provide a [mre] of what you *actually* tried (even if it doesn't work properly - or at all).

Comment: Just saw your comment, thanks! I will try to improve my question asking skill.

Comment: @Peterthebeerappreciator If you have another problem then create another post. But honestly your main mistake is not knowing how the classes work in python, I recommend you check your notes on that topic. In your case only copy the code from `filename = 'test.mp3'` to `player.play()` and change `player` to `self.player`